# Filtering by parameter & Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MachineInfo view page which I am showing 60 different specifications of the related machine like processor info, ram info, disk info, db info etc.

**ActionLink** to this page is:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Machine Info", "MachineInfo", new { id = Model.LicenseKey }) |
```

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult MachineInfo(string LicenseKey)
    {
        if (LicenseKey == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Farm farm = db.Farms.Find(LicenseKey);
        if (farm == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(farm);
    }
```

**Farm Model:**

```
public partial class Farm
{
    public Farm()
    {
        this.FarmChanges = new HashSet<FarmChange>();
        this.FarmDetails = new HashSet<FarmDetail>();
        this.FarmTables = new HashSet<FarmTable>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LicenseKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FarmChange> FarmChanges { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FarmDetail> FarmDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FarmTable> FarmTables { get; set; }
}
```

**FarmDetails Model:**

```
public partial class FarmDetail
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int FarmId { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Farm Farm { get; set; }
}
```

*All the MachineInfo is coming from the "Value" in the FarmDetails table.*

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<FarmManagement.Models.FarmDetail>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Machine Info";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Machine Info</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Value)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Farm.LicenseKey)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Farm.LicenseKey)
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to Farms List", "Index")
```

I am trying to show MachineInfo of a specific machine (LicenseKey=ABXYZ-XYZAB) with this url: **mydomain.com/MachineInfo/ABXYZ-XYZAB**

I need to *filter* the view by *LicenseKey*.

After my all tries, I'm only getting 400 - Bad Request error (Because LicenseKey == null) or getting the MachineInfo of **ALL** machines, not the specific machine with LicenseKey=ABXYZ-XYZAB.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: instead of `public ActionResult MachineInfo(string LicenseKey)` use `public ActionResult MachineInfo(string id)` .... `LicenseKey` will always be null because you are not setting anything in it...

Comment: @Kartikeya it is giving an error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Farm_BDB4A56137C4065DC20A78957B4843D725D3B41972D06982AC6CA0308623C051', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FarmManagement.v2.Models.FarmDetail]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem after making following changes:

**New Controller After Change:**

```
public ActionResult MachineInfo(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            FarmDetail farmdetail = db.FarmDetails.Where(x => x.FarmId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (farmdetail == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(farmdetail);
        }
```

**New View After Change:**

```
@model FarmManagement.Models.FarmDetail

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Machine Info";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Machine Info</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
        </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
         </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Value)
        </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Farm.LicenseKey)
         </th>
         <th></th>
     </tr>

 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Farm.FarmDetails.Count(); i++)
 {
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Farm.FarmDetails.ElementAt(i).Type)
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Farm.FarmDetails.ElementAt(i).Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Farm.FarmDetails.ElementAt(i).Value)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Farm.LicenseKey)
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Farms List", "Index")
```

I needed to use a where sentence in Controller;

```
FarmDetail farmdetail = db.FarmDetails.Where(x => x.FarmId == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

And removed *IEnumerable* from the View and changed *@foreach* to *@for* with *ElementAt(i)*.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Farm.FarmDetails.ElementAt(i).Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your actionlink code

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Machine Info", "MachineInfo", new { id = Model.LicenseKey })
```

to

`@Html.ActionLink("Machine Info", "MachineInfo", new { LicenseKey = Model.LicenseKey })`

As the Action link parameter name should match with the controller action parameter name.

Comment: That will make the url `.../MachineInfo?LicenseKey=ABXYZ-XYZAB` instead of `.../MachineInfo/ABXYZ-XYZAB` unless OP creates a custom route definition.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are absolutely spot on.

Comment: @shu it is giving another error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Farm_BDB4A56137C4065DC20A78957B4843D725D3B41972D06982AC6CA0308623C051', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FarmManagement.Models.FarmDetail]'

Comment: @EmreBolat it's all together a different issue 
In your view you are using `@model IEnumerable<FarmManagement.Models.FarmDetail>` as model But from the controller action you supplying `Farm farm` as model to view.That's the reason you are getting this error.